# Accidentally deleted all files by rm - rf /* ... In my macbook pro

Tags: macos, osx-lion

some of my collegue deleted all my files by rm - rf /* ... In my macbook pro . Now everything is gone and i am completely locked out.

Now mac logs in with 3 options..

```
1.time machine restore (I dont have any backup)
2.Download and install mac lion (My net is too slow to download 3 gb file)
3.Disk utility repair.
```

I am locked out with 1st and 2nd option...but is there any way to recover my laptop using disk utility ??

I can see macintosh HD image with 47k folders and files and 290 mb space occupied..so i guess some of my files are in there...

Some one please help.

Comment: This is not a programming question and therefore off-topic for Stack Overflow. Try apple.stackexchange.com instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have access to another Mac? If so, you can maybe start your MacBookPro in FireWire Target mode. Essentially, even with a wiped out Operating System, you can press "T" while booting your Mac and it will appear as a FireWire disk to another connected computer - you can then at least copy your files off your MBP to the other computer.

See [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1661?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)
 for details.

ADDED: The slightly harder method, if you have access to another machine, is to remove the disk from your MBP and put it in a USB disk caddy and attach that to another machine. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Chances are good that the files and folders remaining were in the `.*` directories at the root level of your disk which would be things like the trash and laptop-based Time Machine cache.

Unfortunately, unless you have a backup off of the machine, you are pretty much out of luck.  `Disk Utility` only has file system integrity and disk formatting/partitioning tools.

If you have a Time Machine backup, you should be able to boot into Recovery Mode (hold the `alt` and R keys during boot) and then connect the Time Machine disk to restore.

Answer (score 0):

For IntelliJ users, after rm a file, touch that file.
Then go VCS / Local History.

(Can't recall if local history feature was enabled by default, worth a check after an install.)